# Java concurrency in practice: Listing 8.3. Inducing a lock ordering to prevent deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading

I am unable to understand why the code mentioned in the listing 8.3 in the book is not deadlock prone. When I run the code, it doesn't leads to deadlock. I took the idea from the book and modified the code.
Below is the program:-

```
    public class LockOrderingDeadLockSolved {
    private final Object left = new Object();
    private final Object right = new Object();
    private final Object tieLock = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LockOrderingDeadLockSolved obj = new LockOrderingDeadLockSolved();
        int leftHash = System.identityHashCode(obj.left);
        int rightHash = System.identityHashCode(obj.right);
        System.out.println(leftHash +" --- " + rightHash);
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                if (leftHash < rightHash)
                    obj.leftRight();
                else if (leftHash > rightHash)
                    obj.rightLeft();
                else
                    obj.tieLockMethod();
            }
        };
        Thread t1 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                if (leftHash < rightHash)
                    obj.leftRight();
                else if (leftHash > rightHash)
                    obj.rightLeft();
                else
                    obj.tieLockMethod();
            }
        };
        t.start();
        t1.start();

    }

    private void leftRight() {
        synchronized (left) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            synchronized (right) {
                System.out.println("Left right -- left right lock");
            }
        }
    }

    private void rightLeft() {
        synchronized (right) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            synchronized (left) {
                System.out.println("Right left -- right left lock");
            }
        }
    }

    private void tieLockMethod() {
        synchronized (tieLock) {
            synchronized (left) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                synchronized (right) {
                    System.out.println("Right left --- tie lock");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:-

865113938 --- 1442407170

Left right -- left right lock

Left right -- left right lock

**Deadlock prone program:-**

```
public class LockOrderingDeadLock {
private final Object left = new Object();
private final Object right = new Object();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LockOrderingDeadLock obj = new LockOrderingDeadLock();
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            obj.leftRight();
        }
    };
    Thread t1 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            obj.rightLeft();
        }
    };
    t.start();
    t1.start();

}

private void leftRight() {
    synchronized (left) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        synchronized (right) {
            System.out.println("Left right");
        }
    }
}

private void rightLeft() {
    synchronized (right) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        synchronized (left) {
            System.out.println("Right left");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why would there be a deadlock?  One thread will get `left` first, then when it's done the other will go.

Comment: But, if i remove the conditions to check the hash code comparison, it is leading to deadlock.

Comment: Your deadlock-prone program is doing a completely different thing than your non-deadlock-prone program, so that's why the one deadlocks and the other doesn't.  You can't compare two threads running the same method against two threads running different methods and expect them to act the same way.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understood it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If the locks are acquired in the same order the deadlock won't happen.

To make your example deadlock you have to repeatedly acquire the same locks in a different order. This can be done with the following code.

```
private static final Object left = new Object();
private static final Object right = new Object();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (left) {
                synchronized (right) {
                    System.out.println("Left right -- left right lock");
                }
            }
        }
    });
    Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (right) {
                synchronized (left) {
                    System.out.println("Right left -- right left lock");
                }
            }
        }
    });
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
```